# Sequential multi-curl requests on telnet

Tags: php, sockets, curl, multiprocessing, telnet

I am firing a multi-curl request on a port on the localhost.. But these, calls are getting executed sequentially. However, when I fire these requests from a different host, then these calls get executed in parallel..

Please help me in this... I am writing my code below:

```
<?php
// create both cURL resources
$ch1 = curl_init();
$ch2 = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "telnet://127.0.0.1:10000");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_TELNET);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "telnet://127.0.0.1:10000");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_TELNET);


$mh = curl_multi_init();

//add the two handles
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch1);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch2);

$active = null;
//execute the handles
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
}

//close the handles
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch1);
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch2);
curl_multi_close($mh);
```

Comment: I realized this that parallel calls are happening for curl version <= 7.19.0; but after that, calls are executed as sequential.. 

Is there a reason behind this ?

Comment: The curl_multi requests should always run in parallel. If you are getting results sequentially then I suspect this may be a result of blocking in whatever the listening server is.